# Phonegap pinch and zoom to scale canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, cordova, pinchzoom

So I recently found out that an HTML5 canvas has maximum dimensions. This makes sense for memory and efficiency reasons. What would be the smoothest way to scale a context within a canvas element in phone gap. For example, how would I create an infinite pannable and zoomable canvas, similar to google maps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use javascript to handle multi-touch gestures.  There are plenty of libraries that make this easier to do. [Sencha touch](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/touch/examples/production/kitchensink/#demo/touchevents),  or [Hammer.js](http://eightmedia.github.io/hammer.js/) being examples of this. Then you would have to scale down your content on your canvas accordingly.

As for something specific to canvas, it will be a little heavier, but I would suggest something like:  [KineticJS](http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/labs/html5-canvas-multi-touch-scale-stage-with-kineticjs/)